# Обнуление идентификаторов в ColumnModel при добавлении колонки

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Вечер добрый. Есть пустая `Jtable`. Колонки в таблицу добавляются через `DefaultTabelModel` и к ним ставится идентификатор - уникальный ID:

```
public void addNode(String name) {
        Node n = graph.addNode(Integer.toString(ID++));
        n.addAttribute("ui.label", name);

        ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addColumn(name);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.getColumnCount() - 1).setIdentifier(n.getId()); //установка идентификатора
}
```

Удаление, по-идее, должно производиться через этот идентификатор:

```
public void deleteNode(Node n) {
        table.removeColumn(table.getColumn(n.getId()));
        graph.removeNode(n);
}
```

Но каждый раз получаю ошибку о не найденном идентификаторе. Как показал дебаггер, при добавлении новой колонки, идентификаторы предыдущих обнуляются. Подскажите, так и предусмотрено? И как это обойти. P.S.: таблица, на данный момент, модифицируется исключительно этими двумя методами.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что в стандартной библиотеке происходит полное пересоздание таблицы, через вызов метода, т.е. остаются только параметры, добавленные в `DataModel`:

```
public void createDefaultColumnsFromModel() {
        TableModel m = getModel();
        if (m != null) {
            // Remove any current columns
            TableColumnModel cm = getColumnModel();
            while (cm.getColumnCount() > 0) {
                cm.removeColumn(cm.getColumn(0));
            }

            // Create new columns from the data model info
            for (int i = 0; i < m.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TableColumn newColumn = new TableColumn(i);
                addColumn(newColumn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Как итог остаётся только хэдер и данные внутри. P.S.: при добавлении через `JTable`, удаления параметров не происходит